# Compiling failed: type alias 'PriceLabel' references itself

Tags: swift, swiftui

I get this error when I try to preview PriceLabel, however it builds successfully. The strangest part is that my code doesn't contain any typealias.
I have restarted Xcode, but without any change.

I get the error in the top left of the canvas.
[image]

See code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PriceLabel: View {
    let price: Int
    static let currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","
        currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator = " "
        currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

        return currencyFormatter
    }()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Path { path in
                let width: CGFloat = 23
                let height: CGFloat = 24
                let arrowWidth = height / 2.0
                let cornerRadius = height / 7.5

                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: .zero, clockwise: true)
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: true)
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: arrowWidth + cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 135), clockwise: true)
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height / 2.0), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 135), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 225), clockwise: true)
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: arrowWidth + cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 225), endAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), clockwise: true)
                path.closeSubpath()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Text("\(type(of: self).currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: price))!):-")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct PriceLabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PriceLabel(price: 25)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the preview provider really within the `PriceLabel` struct? It's normally outside of it.

Comment: With Xcode 11.2 compiled & Preview as expected. Anyway try to use `PriceLabel. currencyFormatter` instead of `type(of: self).currencyFormatter` - it is surplus.

Comment: I have tried to change that, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Tested with Xcode 11.4b2 - works fine. It looks like the origin is not in the provided code.

Comment: Your code is working good.

Comment: Nope it doesn't. The origin is above the Canvas,it says Failed to build and if I click on the i in the circle I get the error

Comment: Please, be so kind and provide more info. Screenshots, error codes, gif etc. People could not reproduce your error so they couldn't help you with the answer.

Comment: I have updated the original question and included screenshot.

Comment: You don’t happen to have another type named PriceLabel in your project or maybe you simply need to clean your project

Comment: Nope, and I have cleaned it many times.

Comment: What is the name of your target? I'm getting this error when the type has the same name as the target module...

Comment: Thank you, that's was what caused the problem

Comment: Thanks @Alladinian. I had this issue and changing the struct name so it was different from the target name fixed it. Could you post this as an answer to help others? The solution is a bit buried in comments and I almost missed it. And maybe Anders could mark it correct.

Comment: @AndersFrohm Glad it helped. I have posted it as an answer to help other people too.

Comment: @Obliquely Done. I almost forgot about this comment, I just saw the responses and posted it as an answer. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that whatever type is causing the problem, doesn't have the same name as your target module.